# How to limit generation of special characters in cryptojs module

Tags: javascript

I am using cryptojs library to generate a encryption key as:

```js
    const encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('someValue', 'someKey', { 
      keySize: 128 / 8, 
      iv: iv, 
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 
    });
```

output-> wrgbckgwev+=qwe/tfv456bljsfs=

what is happening is i encode this value to something like wrgbckgwev%2s=qwe%2Ftfv456bljsfs= and pass it as a route param to Angular router and then try to decode that value after extracting from the params.

If I generate a encryption key and that key does not contain '/' then it works fine but if it contains '/' then Angular router doesn't process the request and it breaks and it breaks in when I build using prod build during local build using webpack it works fine.

My question is if there any way to control the generation or limit certain characters in the output of the algorithm, one way is that I do the replace in both sides but I am looking more at the configuration side of the algorithm to control this behavior.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: give it a base64 encoding rather than using `encodeURIComponent` use `btoa` see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

% and / are not going to be allowed in then url. You should baseencode the key and send it in the url.

Comment: I am using encodeURIComponent() which is converting '/' to '%2F' but it breaks the params in Angular router